# Simple perceptron model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I'm getting this type error when i'm running the fit function. Many say it runs in python 2.7. I want to how to get it done in python 3. Are there any other ways to do it?

```
class Perceptron:

    def __init__(self):
        self.w=None
        self.b=None

    def model(self,x):
        return 1 if (np.dot(self.w,x)>=self.b) else 0

    def predict(self,X):
        Y=[]
        for x in X:
            result = self.model(x)
            Y.append(result)
        return np.array(Y)

    def fit(self, X, Y, epochs = 1, lr=1):
        self.w = np.ones(X.shape[1])
        self.b = 0

        accuracy = {}
        max_accuracy = 0

        wt_matrix = []

        for i in range(epochs):
            for x, y in zip(X,Y):
                y_pred = self.model(x)
                if y==1 and y_pred == 0:
                    self.w = self.w +lr* x
                    self.b = self.b + lr*1
                elif y==0 and y_pred== 1:
                    self.w = self.w-lr*x
                    self.b = self.b-lr*1
            wt_matrix.append(self.w)
            accuracy[i] =  accuracy_score(self.predict(X),Y)
            if(accuracy[i]>max_accuracy):
                max_accuracy = accuracy[i]
                chkptw=self.w
                chkptb=self.b
        self.w =chkptw
        self.b=chkptb

        print(max_accuracy)



        plt.plot(accuracy.values())
        plt.ylim([0,1])
        plt.show   

        return np.array(wt_matrix)
```

This is the code:

```
wt_matrix = perceptron.fit(X_train,Y_train,100)
```

and when im calling the funtion 
it showing this type error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-8b850a516f0e> in <module>()

----> 1 wt_matrix = perceptron.fit(X_train,Y_train,100)


8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple problem of typecasting. Change

```
plt.plot(accuracy.values())
```

to

```
plt.plot(list(accuracy.values()))
```